# How to create toolbox same as the toolbox for workflow designer?

Tags: c#, workflow, workflow-activity, t4-toolbox

I'm trying to build a toolbox just same as the one for workflow designer. All the workflow activities/elements should be listed in 10 categories of activity designers
(Control Flow, Flowchart, State Machine, Messaging, Runtime, Primitives, Transaction, Collection, Error Handling, Migration).

I have tried to load all the activities of workflow from assembly, but there are some problem.

1). Names of activities are not be displayed completely. For example, AddToCollection will be shown as AddToCollection'1. How to show them completely?

2). All the activities are collected in a category 'System.Activities.Statements'. Because i don't know how to group them according to above categories. So i just load the assembly 'System.Activities.Statements' and add all i got in a pot. Any idea to group them?

```
 private static ToolboxControl CreateToolboxControl()
 {
    const string @namespace = "System.Activities.Statements";
    var toolbox = new ToolboxControl();
    var cat = new ToolboxCategory(@namespace);
    ToolboxItemWrappers(typeof(Flowchart).Assembly, @namespace).ToList().ForEach(cat.Add);
    if (cat.Tools.Count > 0)
        toolbox.Categories.Add(cat);
    return toolbox;        
  }

  private static IEnumerable<ToolboxItemWrapper> ToolboxItemWrappers(Assembly assembly, string @namespace)
  {
    if (assembly == null)
    {
      throw new ArgumentNullException("assembly");
    }
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(@namespace))
    {
        return Enumerable.Empty<ToolboxItemWrapper>();
    }

    var q = from type in assembly.GetTypes()
            where string.Equals(type.Namespace, @namespace)
            && type.IsPublic && !type.IsNested && !type.IsAbstract
            && type.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes) != null
            orderby type.Name
            select new ToolboxItemWrapper(type);
    return q;
  }
```

3). Some activities are not in my list. e.g. All in the category 'Messaging' dosn't exist. How can i get them from assembly or with another way?

Thanks a lot!

Ivan